# When to use of TestContext#verify() method in vert.x

Tags: junit, vert.x

I was working on a unit test for the sample vert.x app. But could not understand the purpose of `TestContext#verify()` method. Here are two test cases one with `TestContext#verify()` and another without it. Both are running fine. So when do we need to use `TestContext#verify()`?

Test Case without `TestContext#verify()`:

```
@Test
    @DisplayName("Handler Test3")
    void successTestCase1(VertxTestContext testContext) {
      Checkpoint checkpoint = testContext.checkpoint(1);
      new SampleVerticle().doWorkWithAsyncresult("hello",
              testContext.succeeding(future -> {
                assertThat(future).isEqualTo("test from");
                testContext.completeNow();
              })
      );
    }
```

Test Case with `TestContext#verify()`:

```
@Test
  @DisplayName("Handler Test4")
  void successTestCase2(VertxTestContext testContext) {
    Checkpoint checkpoint = testContext.checkpoint(1);
    new SampleVerticle().doWorkWithAsyncresult("vivek",
            testContext.succeeding(future -> {
              testContext.verify(() -> {
                assertThat(future).isEqualTo("test from");
                testContext.completeNow();
              });
            })
    );
  }
```

Test Method:

```
public void doWorkWithAsyncresult(String input, Handler<AsyncResult<String>> handler) {
  handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture("test from"));
}
```

Thanks,
Vivek Kumar

Answer (score 2):

The `verify` method is useful when the test fails, not when it passes.

If one of the asynchronous assertions fails, `verify` will report it correctly to the `TestContext`. Then the test will fail immediately with the right error message.

Otherwise the test would timeout after an arbitrary amount of time, and the error may or may not be printed to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You code is not async. So both methods are same now. And `testContext.completeNow()` does nothing.

When code is async you should add to the bottom of test (`VertxExtension` does this for you):

```
assertTrue(testContext.awaitCompletion(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS), "Timeout");
assertFalse(testContext.failed());
```

And if `assert` throws exception, the test without `verify` will end with timeout.

To fix that you should wrap your `assert` and call `failNow`:

```
try {
    assert...
    testContext.completeNow();
} catch (Exception e) {
    textContext.failNow(e);
    return;
}
```

`TextContext::verify` does this wrapping for you.